# My dad wants to transfer money from India to US as a family maintanance

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, gift-tax, child-care

What is the tax implication if my dad is sending money to me here in US as a family maintenance? Do I have to pay tax on that money and how much will that be?

Comment: What is your tax residency status in India and US

Comment: I am on H1-B in US and in India I have NRE status ..

Answer (score 3):

As the funds are Gift received from your parents, and your tax residency is US, as per US gift tax, there is no tax due from you for these funds.